# Intuition of Baire's Category Theorem on C[0,1]?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, baire-category

In *Understanding Analysis* by Stephen Abbott, I have understood that
Baire's Category Theorem applied on C[0,1] tells us that there are much more nowhere-differentiable continuous functions than those with derivative at on one point.

And this implies that most of continuous functions cannot be written as a countable union of nowhere-dense sets, and that continuous functions that are differentiable at least one point can be written as a countable union of nowhere-dense sets.

However, I am not sure if I understand what it means for a function to be written as a countable union of nowhere-dense sets.

**Is there a visual, intuitive way to see how can a function be written or not written as a union of sets?**

**And why *can* a continuous function that has derivative at least one point be expressed as a countable union of nowhere-dense sets?**

Quoting Abbott,

"Now, in this space we will se that the collection of continuous functions that are differentiable at even one point *can* be written as the countable union of nowhere-dense sets." (97)

Comment: It's not "a function written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets", it's "a set of functions written as a countable union of nowhere dense sets".

Comment: You seem to be mixing up "a single function" and "a set of functions". It's the *SET* of functions that is a countable union of nowhere dense sets, not a single function. (Technically, I guess if we interpret "single function" as a set containing a single function, then it will be a countable union of nowhere dense sets, because in fact it's nowhere dense, by virtue of being a set containing a single point of the space. But I don't think this is what you mean.)

Comment: Oh, that clears the confusion I had; thank you so much for the help!